# how to realize bundle splitting that I want do split one bundle file into two bundle files?

Tags: webpack

i'm trying to figure out bundle splitting but the documentation is confusing
my goal is to split bundle.js into two bundles; `addon.js` which contains my app logic, and `vendor.js` which contains all of my NPM modules

this is my current optimize property

```
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          name: 'addon',
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

what it's doing is putting both vendor and app code into `addon.js` and creating a `bundle.js` which only has bootstrap code, as i'm guessing it's still the entrypoint. what am I doing wrong? i don't understand what cache groups are supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a `default`, and try `test: /node_modules/` for your vendor test
Mine is just

```
                commons: {
                    test: /node_modules/,
                    name: "vendor",
                    chunks: "all",
                },
```

and it works, the app code goes in a bundle named by `output.filename` and everything from `node_modules` goes into `vendor-{hash}.js`
I've had issues trying to include path separators in `test` before